# filter multiple role id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hi try to do something and I can't do multiple id in filter
and that's only detecting the first id pls help
the command:

```
    
  const member = 
  message.mentions.members.first() || 
  message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

  if(!member) return message.reply('תתייג משהו')

  const memberRoles = member.roles.cache
  .filter((roles) => roles.id == '851427310656552972' || '855439580668231703' || '754739387295858828' || '780692233367060521' || '851089257044508682' || '754743308852527166' || '849632562724995144' || '796320719972859955')
  .map((role) => role.toString());

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.filter((roles) => roles.id == '851427310656552972' || roles.id == '855439580668231703' || roles.id == '754739387295858828' || roles.id == '780692233367060521' || roles.id == '851089257044508682' || roles.id == '754743308852527166' || roles.id == '849632562724995144' || roles.id == '796320719972859955')
```

or just make an array and check if the role is included:

```
let rolesFilter = ['851427310656552972', '855439580668231703', '754739387295858828', '780692233367060521', '851089257044508682', '754743308852527166', '849632562724995144', '796320719972859955']
.filter((roles) => rolesFilter.includes(roles.id)
```